# Upgrading CPU on Dell inspiron 580

Tags: cpu, motherboard, upgrade, dell-inspiron

I want to upgrade my i5 650 cpu on my dell inspiron pre built computer, since the i5 650 is very weak for gaming. The motherboard is OEM with [chipset H57](http://ark.intel.com/products/42700/Intel-H57-Express-Chipset). I am between 3 CPUS:

> 1) i7 870
>   2) xeon x3470
>   3) i5 760 or  i5 750

Some useful information about my pc:

```
Manufacturer    Dell Inc.
Model   0C2KJT (CPU 1)
Version A00
Chipset Vendor  Intel
Chipset Model   Havendale/Clarkdale Host Bridge
Chipset Revision    18
Southbridge Vendor  Intel
Southbridge Model   H57
Southbridge Revision    06

BIOS
Brand   Dell Inc.
Version A07
Date    13-Nov-10
```

Dell has only tested the `i5 750` with dell inspirons 580, so it is the only cpu that works for sure on my board. Though, in the cpu chipset page `i7 870` is listed there but the similar `xeon x3470` not. I don't know what to do, should i risk it to get the i7 870 or the xeon since they have 8 threads?

My thread in Tom's Hardware: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3469954/intel-core-760-870-xeon-x3460-x3470-gaming-socket-1156-chipset-h57.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check those user benchmarks on http://www.userbenchmark.com. These benchmarks of the users who have exactly the same motherboard and pc as mine, confirm that i7 870 and Xeon x3470 are compatible with my system:

**i7 780:**

http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/2199791.

**Xeon X3470:**

http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/3620875

**My Benchmarks:**

http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/4384287

So this is a proof that those CPUs are going to work on my board.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer i7, xeon is usually meant for servers. Not sure if it will fit motherboard though.

Researched and found your motherboard Processor Support LGA 1156.
And Intel Core Supports i3/ i5/ i7 **(8xx models only)**: 1156
And your i7 processor is a **x870**.
Both those i5 should work.

[image]

**With your current OEM built computer, the i5 will be best compatible. With the i7 you may experience some bottleneck due to your 2gb GPU. In this case, it would be wise to go with the i5 unless you intend to upgrade the GPU. Overclocking the i5 or GPU will cause more heat and higher voltage and could experience frustrating issues trying to get the computer to maximum performance without issues.

Comment: Sorry i meant i7 870

Comment: well in that case, it should work then. As long as it is compatible with the BIOS. @csandreas1

Comment: So xeon should work too both i7 and xeon are similar

Comment: i added a picture for the xeon, it looks like it is also supported. Although, still... not sure about BIOS. may need to upgrade it.

Comment: Cant update bios it is OEM,  comes from dell.

Comment: Tough to say if i7 or xeon will work. Both i5 should definitely work. I would get in contact with Dell to make sure. In my experience I have found that i7 is much faster than Xeon and that would be the way to go. @csandreas1

Comment: Those two i7 870 and x3470 are the same. Compare them in userbenchmark.  Xeon is half the price in AliExpress

Comment: I have already contacted them but they have only tested the i5 750. Other guy in the forum claimed that the i7 870 worked on his dell inspiron 580 pc

Comment: They may be identical but still xeon is meant for servers not desktops. In my experience i7 is much better than xeon for desktop use. I think it is worth the risk to go for the i7 over the i5 it is major improvement. @csandreas1

Comment: I know but also the 40 euros cheaper i5 760 would be an improvement since it is quad core.. By the way my gpu is the  rx 460. Would i get gpu bottleneck with i7?

Comment: With your rx 460 you may not get everything out of the i7 so yes it will be bottleneck a little. If you intend to keep that gpu, it would be sufficient to get the i5 760. The i5 should be sufficient for good gaming. @csandreas1

Comment: Can i overclock it?

Comment: Overclocking can be tricky. it depends on the game you are playing, how your cooling is setup, may need to add more fans. Adding more fans means you need more power, so may need a bigger power supply. Make sure your PC is in an area thats not too tight so that it can get the proper ventilation. Then try overclocking to where you get your best performance. Then after all that, your GPU life will be shorter. @csandreas1

Comment: Same stands for cpu overclock?

Comment: Essentially yeah @csandreas1

Comment: Thank you i cant mark ur answer because ur comments helped me better of you can combine some comments to the answer i will select as best answer

Comment: Forget i7 780 i meant i7 870it was a typing error

Comment: check my answer , what do you think? Comment on my answer

Comment: can't comment everywhere yet. Links look good, you're good to go. @csandreas1

Comment: yep xeon x3470 works on my system eventually. i get bottlenecks on games that are not well threaded like cs go and LOL

Comment: cs go and LOL are not very intense games. I play LOL on a core 2 duo and it works fine with a good graphics card. I use fiber optic cabling and have fast internet. @csandreas1 the i7 would have been the better way to go. Upgrade that GPU or ISP.

Comment: yes but my gpu cant perform at the maximum performance at those games that are not optimize to use all threads, so i get unstable fps and gpu usage bouncing